# Set asp:ImageButton ViewState from javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, viewstate, imagebutton

I extend `System.Web.UI.WebControls.ImageButton` control:
`EnableViewState` server property of the control is set to `true`.`OnClientClick` is set to `setNextImageSrc(this);return false;`. In javascript function `setNextImageSrc` I correctly change this control `src` and `alt` attributes. But I don't get ViewState working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't set viewstate from javascript - viewstate is meant to persist server state, also if you have decent security settings it is encrypted and has got hash signature. If you need something from client for server, make a hidden field next to button and set the hidden field value instead.

Comment: That's what I'am  doing right now, but it feels like "inventing a bicycle".